# Show that for $1 \le p < r < \infty$, these holds $(f|f|^p)^{1/p} \le (f|f|^r)^{1/r}.$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu(x) < \infty$, and define, for $f \in L^1$, the average of $\int f d\mu$ to be $\frac1{\mu(x)} \int f d\mu$. Show that for $1 \le p < r < \infty$, these holds $$(f|f|^p)^{1/p} \le (f|f|^r)^{1/r}.$$ In particular, if $\mu(x) = 1$ (i.e. $\mu$ is a probability measure), then $||f||_p \le ||f||_r$.

I really don't know how to solve this question.

I think that $(f|f|^p)^{1/p} = (f^{1/p}|f|) \ge (f^{1/r}|f|)$ for $p<r$. Isn't it?
Could you give any hint please?

Comment: Please use \int within $ signs  for integral sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you studied Holder's inequality. All you have to do is think of $|f|^{p}$ as the product of $|f|^{p}$ constant function $1$ and apply Holder's inequality to the exponents $\frac r p$ and $\frac r {r-p}$. Let $p_1=\frac r p$ and $q_1=\frac r {r-p}$. Then $p_1>1,q_1>1$ and $\frac 1 {p_1} +\frac 1 {q_{1}}=1$. Therefore  $\int |f|^{p} \leq (\int ({|f|^{p}}^{p_1}))^{1/p_1} (\int 1)^{1/q_1}$. Now just plug in the values of $p_1$ and $q_1$ and take p-th roots on both sides.

Comment: Thank you for comment. My textbook says that Holder's inequality is that if $f \in L^p$ and $g \in L^q$, then $|fg| \in L^1$, and $\int$$|fg| \ge ||f||_p||g||_q$ with $1/p + 1/q =1$. I still don't really understand your hint. Could you please expand a little bit?

Comment: @Daeseon I have added some details to the proof.

Comment: I think you use $|f|^p \in L^{p_1}$. How can we know that? and I am also wondering how this can show the first inequality ($(f|f|^p)^{1/p}\le(f|f|^q)^{1/q}$) of the question.

Comment: @Daeseon If $\int |f|^{r}=\infty$ there is nothing to prove. Hence we may assume that  $\int (|f|^{p})^{p_1}=\int |f|^{r}<\infty$

Comment: @Daeseon I am assuming that some of the $f$'s in the question are supposed to be integral signs. If you really mean what you have typed then the question makes absolutely no sense at all and you should delete this question.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you said in a comment above. I guess I wrote wrong in lecture. Thank you!